# Query returns boolean after adding "WHERE date BETWEEN" statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The query runs very well without limiting it with date statement "BETWEEN ** AND **". When i add date limiting it returns a boolean instead of grouping the result through a loop.

Here's my code

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT blood_type WHERE date BETWEEN '". 
$startingdate."' AND '". $endingdate ."',
count(*) AS donor_count FROM donors GROUP BY blood_type");
```

and this is the loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $resultArray[] = $row;  
}
```

that throw this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean
```

Any idea of why it doesn't return an array as it should be?

**Edit:**

I receive the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-04-20' AND '2015-05-18', count(*) AS donor_count FROM d' at line 1

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-04-20' AND '2015-05-18', count(*) AS donor_count FROM d' at line 1

Comment: your `FROM` is in the wrong spot/query ordering. See the answers below.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything else. You may need to show us more code and if you are indeed using `mysqli_` to connect with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i read the apache's error log with everytime i get an error it prints the same error... and yes i'm using fully mysqli..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print out the SQL, when you want to debug something.  Your query is something like this:

```
SELECT blood_type
WHERE date BETWEEN '". $startingdate."' AND '". $endingdate ."',
count(*) AS donor_count
FROM donors
GROUP BY blood_type;
```

Although constructed of SQL clauses, it is gibberish.  I think you want:

```
SELECT blood_type, count(*) as donor_count
FROM donors
WHERE date BETWEEN '". $startingdate."' AND '". $endingdate ."'
GROUP BY blood_type;
```

The order of the clauses in a SQL statement is fixed.  If you put them in the wrong order, you will get an error.  Your code should be checking for such errors.

Also, the dates should really be parameterized rather than embedded into the query string.

Comment: Good idea mate!!!! it's more clear now. altho i tried your code and it still shot the same error..

Comment: `$startingdate."' AND '". $endingdate ."',` <= extra comma? Shouldn't be there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm wondering if OP needs to escape their data at this point. MySQL may be complaining about that and is hard to say exactly what those variables are assigned as/from.

Comment: @Alamri I see you accepted the answer. So, was it the extra (trailing) comma from earlier?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Guys this worked !!! yes the problem with Gordon's solution was in that little comma :D. I see now so it was about sorting the query in a correct order :). Thanks alot guys.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do here but if you want to count donors between a certain period of time grouped by blood-type, you query should like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT blood_type, count(*) as donor_count WHERE date BETWEEN '". $startingdate."' AND '". $endingdate ."' GROUP BY blood_type");
```

which translates to something like this:

```
select blood_type, count(*) as donor_count WHERE date between '2015-05-10' and '2015-05-16' group by blood_type
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want to do thanks, but I tried your query and still get the same problem. it returns a boolean.

Comment: @Alamri, look at Gordon's answer.  This is essentially duplicated but with errors.